# How can I align text next to a container and stop it from overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I have a website that shows star ratings. Next to the stars, I would like to show the numerical score that accompanies the number of stars. However, the CSS properties that enable the stars to show correctly is causing the text that I would like to display to overlap with the stars on my page. To better illustrate the problem, I have included a code snippet.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header header header'
    'nav article ads'
    'nav footer footer';
  grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px;
  grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr 15%;
  grid-row-gap: 1px;
  grid-column-gap: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  color: #0ad05b;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: #e3eaee;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.2em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  font-size: 14px;
}
footer,
article,
nav,
div {
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #061621;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  font-size: 14px;
}
textarea {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#pageHeader {
  grid-area: header;
}
#pageFooter {
  grid-area: footer;
}
#mainArticle {
  grid-area: article;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#mainArticleShip {
  grid-area: article;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#mainNav {
  grid-area: nav;
}
#siteAds {
  grid-area: ads;
}
/* Form Style */
#mainArticleForm {
  background: linear-gradient(50deg, rgba(6, 22, 33, 0.5), rgb(0, 0, 0)),
    url(https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
#mainArticle {
  background: linear-gradient(15deg, rgba(6, 22, 33, 0.7), rgb(0, 0, 0)),
    url(https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/bg.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
.innerArticleSignup {
  background: transparent;
}
.innerArticleForm {
  width: 65%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent;
}
.text {
  background: transparent;
}
.reviewForm {
  background: transparent;
}
.innerArticleForm h1 {
  color: #e3eaee;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.innerArticleForm h2 {
  color: #e3eaee;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
form {
  padding: 39px;
}
.form__group {
  background: #000000a1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.form__group label {
  width: 232px;
  display: inline;
  text-align: left;
}
.form__group select {
  padding: 6px;
  float: right;
}
.form__group input {
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  float: right;
}
.form__group textarea {
  font-size: 14px;
  float: right;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  color: #767676;
}

.primary {
  padding: 8px 18px;
  margin: 22px 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  background: #0ad05b;
  border: 2px solid #989898;
}
.innerArticle {
  height: 17vh;
  width: 17vh;
  background: transparent;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
.big-user-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.userAvatar {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.mainPage {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
.headerRight {
  grid-area: header;
  justify-self: right;
  padding: 1.2em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
}
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
}

.left {
  background: #21313c;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #e3eaee;
  align-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  justify-content: left;
}

.form-user-photo {
  height: 15rem;
  width: 15rem;
}

.alert {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 9999;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  padding: 1.6rem 15rem;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  box-shadow: 0 2rem 4rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.alert--success {
  background-color: #0ad05b;
}
.alert--error {
  background-color: #eb4d4b;
}
.stars-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: transparent;
}

.stars-container:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '★★★★★';
  color: lightgray;
}

.stars-container:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '★★★★★';
  color: gold;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.stars-0:after {
  width: 0%;
}
.stars-10:after {
  width: 10%;
}
.stars-20:after {
  width: 20%;
}
.stars-30:after {
  width: 30%;
}
.stars-40:after {
  width: 40%;
}
.stars-50:after {
  width: 50%;
}
.stars-60:after {
  width: 60%;
}
.stars-70:after {
  width: 70%;
}
.stars-80:after {
  width: 80%;
}
.stars-90:after {
  width: 90%;
}
.stars-100:after {
  width: 100;
}

.shipImage {
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 10%;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 175px;
  height: auto;
}

.otherShips {
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
/* Stack the layout on small devices/viewports. */
@media all and (max-width: 575px) {
  body {
    grid-template-areas:
      'header'
      'article'
      'ads'
      'nav'
      'footer';
    grid-template-rows: 80px 1fr 70px 1fr 70px;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .form__group {
    display: block;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1250px) {
  .innerArticleForm,
  .reviewForm,
  form {
    padding: 0;
  }
  .innerArticleForm {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 557px) {
  .innerArticleForm {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>CruiseCrunch | Symphony of the Seas Reviews</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link
    rel="shortcut icon"
    type="image/ico"
    href="https://cruisecrunch.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/favicon.ico"
  />
  <link
    rel="stylesheet"
    href="/style.css"
  />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="[FONT AWESOME LINK]" />
  <meta
    property="og:title"
    content="CruiseCrunch | Cruise Research And Reviews"
  />
  <meta property="og:type" content="website" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="https://www.cruisecrunch.com" />
  <meta property="og:image" itemprop="image" content="/img/thumbnail.jpg" />
</head>
<body>
  <header id="pageHeader">
    <div class="left">
      <a href="/"
        ><img
          class="logo"
          src="/logo.png"
      /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p><a href="/signup">Sign up</a> | <a href="/login">Login</a></p>
    </div>
  </header>
  <article id="mainArticleReviews">
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Symphony of the Seas Reviews</h2>
      <a href="/addreview"><i class="fa fa-plus"> </i> Add Review<br /><br /></a
      >The Symphony of the Seas has an average rating of 5. There are 2 ratings
      for this ship.<br /><br />
      <span class="stars-container stars-50">
      ★★★★★
      </span>5.0<br /><br /><br /><img
        class="shipImage"
        src="/img/ships/symphonyoftheseas.jpg"
        alt="Symphony of the Seas"
      />
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="innerArticleR">
      <b class="span">CruiseFan on October 18th, 2020:</b><br /><br /><span
        >Sail Date: February, 2018</span
      ><br /><span
        >Review: It was pretty great. The food was amazing, but everything was
        expensive.</span
      >
    </div>
    <div class="innerArticleR">
      <b class="span"> Turtle McTurtleston on October 21st, 2020:</b
      ><br /><br /><span>Sail Date: January, 2019</span><br /><span
        >Review: LOVED Symphony of the Seas and all it had to offer. The salad
        bar was fabulous but would love to see grubs. I love that this ship has
        many ways of socializing for turtles like me to come out of their shell.
        Definitely recommend.
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>Other Royal Caribbean International Ships</h2>
      <br />
    </div>
    <article id="mainArticleShip">
      <div class="innerArticle">
        <a href="/ship/allure-of-the-seas"
          ><img
            class="mainPage"
            src="/img/ships/allureoftheseas.jpg"
            alt="Allure of the Seas" /></a
        ><br /><br /><a href="/ship/allure-of-the-seas">Allure of the Seas</a
        ><br /><br />
      </div>
      <div class="innerArticle">
        <a href="/ship/harmony-of-the-seas"
          ><img
            class="mainPage"
            src="/img/ships/harmonyoftheseas.jpg"
            alt="Harmony of the Seas" /></a
        ><br /><br /><a href="/ship/harmony-of-the-seas">Harmony of the Seas</a
        ><br /><br />
      </div>
      <div class="innerArticle">
        <a href="/ship/independence-of-the-seas"
          ><img
            class="mainPage"
            src="/img/ships/independenceoftheseas.jpg"
            alt="Independence of the Seas" /></a
        ><br /><br /><a href="/ship/independence-of-the-seas"
          >Independence of the Seas</a
        ><br /><br />
      </div>
      <div class="innerArticle">
        <a href="/ship/liberty-of-the-seas"
          ><img
            class="mainPage"
            src="/img/ships/libertyoftheseas.jpg"
            alt="Liberty of the Seas" /></a
        ><br /><br /><a href="/ship/liberty-of-the-seas">Liberty of the Seas</a
        ><br /><br />
      </div>
      <div class="innerArticle">
        <a href="/ship/oasis-of-the-seas"
          ><img
            class="mainPage"
            src="/img/ships/oasisoftheseas.jpg"
            alt="Oasis of the Seas" /></a
        ><br /><br /><a href="/ship/oasis-of-the-seas">Oasis of the Seas</a
        ><br /><br />
      </div>
      <div class="innerArticle">
        <a href="/ship/spectrum-of-the-seas"
          ><img
            class="mainPage"
            src="/img/ships/spectrumoftheseas.jpg"
            alt="Spectrum of the Seas" /></a
        ><br /><br /><a href="/ship/spectrum-of-the-seas"
          >Spectrum of the Seas</a
        ><br /><br />
      </div>
    </article>
  </article>
  <nav id="mainNav">
    Navigation
    <div class="nav">
      <div class="ul">
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/"><i class="fa fa-ship"></i> All Ships</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/addreview"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Review</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/topships"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Top Rated Ships</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/bestforkids"><i class="fa fa-child"></i> Best For Kids</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/bestvalue"><i class="fa fa-dollar"></i> Best Value</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/cabins"><i class="fa fa-bed"></i> Best Cabins</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/bestdining"><i class="fa fa-beer"></i> Best Dining</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/entertainment"
            ><i class="fa fa-film"></i> Best Entertainment</a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/worstships"
            ><i class="fa fa-thumbs-down"></i> Lowest Rated Ships</a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/recentreviews"
            ><i class="fa fa-rss-square"></i> Most Recent Reviews</a
          >
        </div>
        <div class="li">
          <a href="/newships"><i class="fa fa-anchor"></i> New Ships</a>
        </div>
        <div class="li"><br /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="siteAds">Over 6 cruise ship reviews!</div>
  <footer id="pageFooter">
    <p class="footer">&#169; 2020, CruiseCrunch</p>
  </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: linebreak `<br>`is an empty tag. It not needs to be closed and as such only be written `<br>`not <br />`

Comment: I was converting from Jade back to HTML and it added a closing tag for the br. I was too lazy to fix it for purposes of the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that this is cuase by:

```
.stars-container {

    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    color: transparent;

}
```

Switch absolute to

```
position:relative;
```

and it will should be fine from what i can see.

Answer (score 0):

make the stars-container position: relative

```
.stars-container {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: transparent;
}
```